# how to auto-size iframe in Apex?

Tags: iframe, salesforce, apex-code, autosize

i'm trying to visualize an other application into my salesforce page. The problem is that the default height of the iframe that contains the other application is too short.
I was finding how to auto resize that but i didn't find anything usefull. I do a workaround that consists in put a big height but it's a very bad solution.

Here is my apex code page:

```
<apex:page controller="CaseManagmentWizard" showHeader="false" sidebar="true" >

<apex:iframe height="3000px" src="{!callCenterAPI}api/start.php?
 apiKey={!apiKey}&
 username={!userIims}&
idCliente={!selectedCustomerId}&
urlOk={!callCenterURLOK}& 
urlError={!callCenterURLError}
"></apex:iframe>

</apex:page>
```

If I put height="100%" is the same than nothing!

[Here's a print of how it's seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN4BR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height of the child page and send to parent to set iframe page height.

Following example code using jQuery

Give an ID to IFrame page.

In the child page(IFrame) write a script to calculate the height of the body using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     window.parent.setFrameStylesFromParent(j$("body").height());
})
```

In the Parent page write a script to set the height of frame page.

```
function setFrameStylesFromParent(paramHeight){
    j$("#iFrameId").height(paramHeight);
}
```

Comment: that was not possible because the same origin policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: sometimes  working but sometimes not working.it throws javascript error saying-'Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.setFrameStylesFromParent is not a function' - my iframe only sfdc call internal page.